# How do I change the breed of specific number of links in netlogo?

Tags: hyperlink, netlogo

I am working on the project where I need to create the specific number of links with breed = active links and rest of the links are inactive links. The code is as follows

```
 ask nodes
  [
   create-inactive-links-to other nodes
    [ 
      hide-link
      let num-links count links
      set msg-passing-freq ( num-links * percentage-links / 100 )
      ask n-of msg-passing-freq inactive-links [
          set breed active-links
          show-link
        ]
    ]
  ]
 layout
end
```

It show an error which states there is already a links with x-turtle and y-turtles as active-link

Comment: thanks @AndrewYoak...

Comment: I can't run NetLogo at the moment to test what you are doing, but `ask n-of msg-passing-freq` should be `ask n-of msg-passing-freq inactive-links`. At the moment, you have told NetLogo how many of something to select (and do the actions in []) but you haven't told it what the 'somethings' are. This should not have passed the green tick syntax checker.

Comment: I just made a mistake a typo error